# Warning in jsp : The tag handler class for "s:form" (org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FormTag) was not found on the Java Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, jsp, struts2

I am unable to resolve a warning in eclipse which says 
The tag handler class for `s:form (org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.FormTag)` was not found on the `Java Build Path`

I have added the `struts2-core-2.3.24.jar` as well as the `standard.jar` and `jstl.jar` to the `WEB-INF/lib`and `build path`.

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

    <html>
    <head>
         <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Hello World From Struts2 - Spring integration</h1>

    <s:form>
         <s:textfield name="firstName" label="First Name"/><br/>
         <s:textfield name="lastName" label="Last Name"/><br/>
    </s:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see my updated edit. @user2805924

Answer (score 7):

If u are using Eclipse, try delete  ' prefix="s" ', then press 'save', then add ' prefix="s" ' back again and press 'save'

Answer (score 1):

Did you add `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>` to your `jsp`?

This may occurs when the associated tag class is missing in your `classpath` or by having different `struts2` versions in your `classpath`. Put all the `struts2` dependencies in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder and remove unnecessary `jar` files from your `lib`.

Finally, `Cleanup` the `classpath` and redo according `Apache's` own `struts2` docs.

Edit:

[Integrating `Struts2` with `Spring` step by step](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-spring-plugin-integration-1.html)

[link](https://programmerhints.wordpress.com/2010/09/16/integrating-struts-2-actions-with-spring3-using-spring-struts-plugin-and-using-di/)

[link](http://techmyguru.com/struts2/index.php?section=18)

Comment: Yes, I added <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%> to my jsp.

Comment: k. so check the remaining.

Comment: My web-app libraries shows only 5 jars - servlet-api.jar, struts2-core-2.3.24.jar, standard.jar, jstl.jar and struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.24.jar.

Comment: Am I missing on any jars?

Comment: are you using `tomcat`. so what is the use of `servlet-api.jar`?

Comment: Yes, I need that jar. Because i get this error without the servlet api jar
The superclass "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" was not found on the Java Build Path

Comment: To enable `Spring` integration, we need to include `struts2-spring-plugin-x-x-x.jar`. are you integrating `Spring`?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am trying to implement this example : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_spring.htm

Comment: I am still not able to resolve this..Infact, my bean class properties are not getting initialized from the applicationContext, is that anyway related to the warning "unknown tag"? Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
    "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
     <beans>
         <bean id="userClass" class="com.tutorialspoint.struts2.User">
         <property name="firstName" value="Michael" />
         <property name="lastName" value="Jackson" />
      </bean>
   </beans>

Comment: see my updated edit. they given step by step explanation.

Comment: @user2805924 You're definitely missing libraries. The `servlet-api.jar` should *not* be deployed with your web app, it is provided by the container. If you're trying to use Spring... you'll need the Spring jar(s). It'd be much better to use Maven or an equivalent dependency management solution.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled a lot in running simple strut2 example and it is all because of 
the configurations issue. I would like to share few points that we need to take care before running struts2 application

1. Folder structure and placing of config files

   - Make sure your struts.xml is under src(source folder) which will move to classes folder after compilation
   - Web.xml should be under Webcontent/WEB-INF folder
2. You should have following jars added to lib folder(version could vary)

   - commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
   - freemarker-2.3.8.jar
   - ognl-2.6.11.jar
   - struts2-core-2.0.11.jar
   - xwork-2.0.4.jar
3. Your index.jsp and other JSPS files are under Webcontent folder

   - Still i was getting 404 error for a very long time and keep on searching web for the solution, but didn't find the proper solution.
   - For me solution was to remove following things (which i have added after seeing few suggestion on internet)
4. Adding of init-param in web.xml under  tag

         config
         struts-default.xml,struts-plugin.xml,../struts.xml

   - This statement is required when you keep your struts.xml at different location and then you are actually specifying it in above lines.
   - My Java class was extended with ActionSupport class which i observed whether you put or not
     it is not makking any difference atleast in my case. ideally it should make difference (Not sure why)
5. Most important point is 
   i have seen the suggestion on few websites which has suggested the following

```html
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

It didn't work for me at all

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>

</filter>
```

Last important point is make sure your build path is updated with all the references(lins).

Comment: `StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter` *doesn't work* because you're using an ancient version of S2.

Answer (score -1):

```
Add the jar file required for jsp. For maven project add following dependency in pom.xml file,
       <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```